# Firing other JavaScripts before AJAX in Chrome / IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

**My Problem:**
I've got this AJAX call inside of my Website that loads some content into a given DIV. While loading this content, a GIF loading animation gets inserted (via JavaScript), until AJAX returns the requested content.

Wich works perfectly fine inside of Firefox, because FF loads the JavaScript in a linear order. Chrome and IE on the other hand do not seem to play that game. It seems that they're firing all AJAX first, then handling everything else.

**Nice to know:**
The async on my AJAX call is FALSE. Yes I know, I should aim for the use of a TRUE async but in this case it just has to be that way.

**My Goal:**
Since I know I can't do anything while my AJAX is loading, I would like to execute the line of code that inserst my animation BEFORE any AJAX gets called. I tried a setTimeout() but that just breaks the whole script.

Any suggestions?

**Here's the code:**

```
<div id="mycolumn">
    <!-- Here: Loading Animation first, then AJAX responseText -->
</div>
```

JavaScript Function:

```
function myAjaxCall () {

    // Initiate HTTP Request
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

    // I want this to happen BEFORE any AJAX gets executed    
    document.getElementById("mycolumn").innerHTML="<img src='loading.gif'>"; 

    // AJAX Request, gets fired by Chrome and IE before anything else, 
    // wich prevents my img from being inserted before the response arrives
    xmlhttp.open("GET","someURL",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    // AJAX Response, replaces my Loading Animation
    document.getElementById("mycolumn").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: What makes you say that IE and Chrome aren't executing the statements in order?

Comment: Could you add a jsbin or something? Your AJAX-method isn't particularly wrong - so we need to see more logic to get a solution.

Comment: What if you preload the loader image? Maybe it's simply due to some latency (maybe the ajax call just ends before the loading image has been fully loaded)

Comment: It is a race condition, use asynchronous calls, synch is bad and locks up the browser.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Well, maybe I got something wrong here. Here's a fiddle that demonstrates my Problem (sry that I didn't provide one in the first place): http://jsfiddle.net/E9Rzj/ - It seems that the responseText injection is my problem. If you comment line 19 you can see what I want to get.